# Ace editor paste button is missing on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I have embedded Ace editor to my web-app and when app is opened on iPhone (Safari or Chrome) - the button "paste" is not shown in the menu.

However, I **do see** this button when:

1. I open my app from Google Chrome's mobile mode
2. I open this page on the iPhone: https://ace.c9.io

The button I am talking about:
[image: Ace web-site]

On my app:

[image: My app]

**UPD**: even more weird - when I open below snippet from iPhone - I also see the button.

So the question is rather - what may cause this button to disappear on my implementation.

The snippet used for embedding:

```js
editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setOptions({
  mode: "ace/mode/python",
  wrap: "off",
  tabSize: 4,
  overwrite: false,
  useWorker: false,
  newLineMode: "auto",
  useSoftTabs: true,
  firstLineNumber: 1,
  indentedSoftWrap: true,
  navigateWithinSoftTabs: false,
 })
```

```css
#editor { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.10.1/ace.js"
        integrity="sha512-U/FB3cdRpCPIpdDLjvLQoqCiupCM95qGrIMZqb99+84XrRQp4EppJ0gfVZAL5kcI9owxxKxrMrrFDJP1RfKAXQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="editor"></div>
```

Comment: Can’t reproduce on my iPhone - the `Paste` option is displayed and fully functional in the snippet above.

Comment: @esqew, deployed the app for you to see it and now I see it as well . It's not working only for local debug (via http) and working via https. Thanks! you actually helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the reason ‍♂️ The button paste is shown only when page is hosted via **https**

I have deployed my application and now see the button. However, it's not shown when debugging locally (over HTTP).

Comment: paste button works only when navigator.clipboard is available. Browsers limit it to localhost and https:// now

Comment: @auser, good to know. Since the app was running on PC and accessing via IP - it was nor localhost neither https